# Folder Action to resize images in Leopard 10.5.8

Tags: applescript, directory

I know nothing about AppleScript, so please forgive me.

Goal is to create a folder that our graphics guy can drop stock photos into and have them resized to 1280.  The chosen folder is a network folder, so don't know if that's part of the issue or not.  He will be pasting the images into the folder from his *Windows* workstation.

Here is what I have pieced together so far:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    repeat with this_item in added_items
        try
            rescale_and_save(this_item)
        end try
    end repeat
end adding folder items to

to rescale_and_save(this_item)
    tell application "Image Events"
        launch
        set the target_height to 1280
        -- open the image file
        set this_image to open this_item

        set typ to this_image's file type

        copy dimensions of this_image to {current_width, current_height}
        if current_height is greater than current_width then
            scale this_image to size target_height
        else
            -- figure out new height
            -- y2 = (y1 * x2) / x1
            set the new_width to (current_width * target_height) / current_height
            scale this_image to size new_width
        end if

        tell application "Finder" to set new_item to ¬
            (container of this_item as string) & "ex" & (name of this_item)
        save this_image in new_item as typ

    end tell
end rescale_and_save
```

I've right clicked on the folder, enabled folder actions, and added my script.  I copy in the test file but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I looked at the samples and came up with the following script that WORKS!:

```
property done_foldername : "Scaled Images"
property target_height : 1280
-- the list of file types which will be processed 
-- eg: {"PICT", "JPEG", "TIFF", "GIFf"} 
property type_list : {"JPEG", "TIFF", "PNGf"}
-- since file types are optional in Mac OS X, 
-- check the name extension if there is no file type 
-- NOTE: do not use periods (.) with the items in the name extensions list 
-- eg: {"txt", "text", "jpg", "jpeg"}, NOT: {".txt", ".text", ".jpg", ".jpeg"} 
property extension_list : {"jpg", "jpeg", "tif", "tiff", "png"}


on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    -- CHECK FOR THE DESTINATION FOLDER WITHIN THE ATTACHED FOLDER
    -- IF IT DOESN'T EXIST, THEN CREATE IT
    tell application "Finder"
        if not (exists folder done_foldername of this_folder) then
            make new folder at this_folder with properties {name:done_foldername}
            set current view of container window of this_folder to list view
        end if
        set the target_folder to folder done_foldername of this_folder
    end tell
    -- PROCESS EACH OF THE ITEMS ADDED TO THE ATTACHED FOLDER
    try
        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in these_items
            set this_item to item i of these_items
            set the item_info to the info for this_item
            -- CHECK TO SEE IF THE ITEM IS AN IMAGE FILE OF THE ACCEPTED FILE TYPE
            if (alias of the item_info is false and the file type of the item_info is in the type_list) or (the name extension of the item_info is in the extension_list) then
                tell application "Finder"
                    -- LOOK FOR EXISTING MATCHING ITEMS IN THE DESTINATION FOLDER
                    -- IF THERE ARE MATCHES, THEN RENAME THE CONFLICTING FILES INCREMENTALLY
                    my resolve_conflicts(this_item, target_folder)
                    -- MOVE THE ITEM TO THE DESTINATION FOLDER
                    set the target_file to (move this_item to the target_folder with replacing) as alias
                end tell
                -- PROCESS THE ITEM
                process_item(target_file)
            end if
        end repeat
    on error error_message number error_number
        if the error_number is not -128 then
            tell application "Finder"
                activate
                display dialog error_message buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1 giving up after 120
            end tell
        end if
    end try
end adding folder items to

on resolve_conflicts(this_item, target_folder)
    tell application "Finder"
        set the file_name to the name of this_item
        if (exists document file file_name of target_folder) then
            set file_extension to the name extension of this_item
            if the file_extension is "" then
                set the trimmed_name to the file_name
            else
                set the trimmed_name to text 1 thru -((length of file_extension) + 2) of the file_name
            end if
            set the name_increment to 1
            repeat
                set the new_name to (the trimmed_name & "." & (name_increment as string) & "." & file_extension) as string
                if not (exists document file new_name of the target_folder) then
                    -- rename to conflicting file
                    set the name of document file file_name of the target_folder to the new_name
                    exit repeat
                else
                    set the name_increment to the name_increment + 1
                end if
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell
end resolve_conflicts

-- this sub-routine processes files 
on process_item(this_item)
    -- NOTE that the variable this_item is a file reference in alias format 
    -- FILE PROCESSING STATEMENTS GOES HERE 
    try
        -- convert alias reference to string
        set this_item to this_item as string
        with timeout of 900 seconds
            tell application "Image Events"
                launch -- always use with Folder Actions
                set this_image to open file this_item
                scale this_image to size target_height
                save this_image with icon
                close this_image
            end tell
        end timeout
    on error error_message
        tell application "Finder"
            activate
            display dialog error_message buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1 giving up after 120
        end tell
    end try
end process_item
```

Comment: The fact that it's a folder shared on a network *shouldn't* cause any trouble. Are you sure you attached the script as Folder Action correctly?

Comment: 6-yr-old solution still holds good! I think you should provide your edited solution as an answer as it actually answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your script on a folder dropping 1 image in, and it turns out it runs repeatedly because the resulting (resized) image is also added to that folder. Here's what it looked like after a couple of seconds, before I interrupted it:

[image: recursive images]

You should have a look at the default image processing scripts inside `/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts` and maybe use one of them as a template. They basically use a sub-folder for the processed images and contain some possibly useful filename conflict resolving function, too.

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I and was able to get it working.  I've posted the working script to my question.